# Looping through data and inserting into a table

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop

I am trying to get data into a table with jquery. The data is in attributes and an array and I would need to go trough that array to extract the information that I require.

Using the following, I put some content into a array:

```
$(Stuff).find("desc").each(function(index) {
    stuffArray[index]=$(this).text();
});
```

Here I put it into a table

```
$("#table").append('<td><a href="'+ siteRoot+'/'+item.url'"></a><td>'+item.title'</td><td>' + stuffArray[i+1] + '</td>');
```

I am guessing that I should loop the stuffArray but I don't know how to do append things like that.

Comment: You're not closing your A tag.

Comment: Neither do you use the `+` (2 times) when you need to concat strings

Comment: Ups, I did close the A tag on my code but it slipped away when I pasted it here. And about that concat thing, so I dont need to + + in that + stuffArray[i+1] + part?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop round the stuffArray and add the contents to the table you can do something like:

```
for(var x=0;x<stuffArray.length;x++){
    $("#table").append('<tr><td>'+stuffArray[x]+'<td></td>'+stuffArray[x]+'</td></tr>');
}
```

see a stripped down example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fermin/zTPeN/1/)

**Update**
In response to your comments:
You still want to loop round but rather than create a new row for each element in StuffArray, add a new `<td>` element to the table, like:

```
var markup = '<tr>';
for(var x=0;x<stuffArray.length;x++){
  markup += '<td>'+stuffArray[x]+'</td>';
}
markup+='</tr>';
$('#table').append(markup);
```

[Updated Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fermin/zTPeN/4/)

Comment: Problem with this is that some of the thing going into table do not come from that stuffArray. And I do like that, then some of the things will come multiple time (the things that dont come from array).

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea what you mean. Where do the other things come from, what do you want from stuffArray?  What do you want the final table to contain?

Comment: Basically this: 

<tr><td>Link</td><td>title</td><td>stuffArray1</td><td>stuffArray2</td><td>StuffArrayX</td></tr> and so on as much as there is stuff in stuffArray

Comment: The link and title comes from different attribute; item.link and item.title.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably enclose the table construction in a for loop then. The structure is like:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < stuffArray.length; i++) {
    $("#table").append('<tr><td><a href="'+ siteRoot+'/'+item.url'"><td>'+item.title'</td><td>' + stuffArray[i+1] + '</td></tr>');

}
```